# Methodology: Design and platform consideration, trade-offs and risks for reporting and analytics

Tags: reporting

**Background**

My question is more about your methodology and your way to approach analytics and reporting.

**Question**

- Which design and platform considerations, trade-offs and risks are you taking into account when designing for reporting and analytics?
- Which constraints are relevant for designing a reporting solution?

Comment: This question is surely too broad for this forum. Can you try to narrow your focus?